# Can you get distances by road from google maps?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I'm trying to build a function for an ASPX webpage (vb back end) that can give a visitor the distance to the nearest branch location we have to where they're signed in from.  I've got the lat/long for our locations, and I can pull their location (albeit not always accurately) from their incoming IP, however I'm trying to figure out how to get back the distance they'd have to travel.  All I've been able to find is the equation (I forget its name) that calculates the distance between points "as the crow flies"... while this would work, technically, to provide them with their nearest branch, it would be nice to be able to include a mileage in that... and obviously that's going to be potentially much different from a straight line between the two points.  Is there a way to send a page request to google maps with a query string of latitude and longitude and receive back a value of calculated distance as they provide on their actual map/directions page?  I read up some on their google maps api, and the javascript to implement it, but I didn't see anything about how to actually implement the functions they have on their page for distance.  Any ideas?

Comment: Seems a quick google search found [Google Maps API - Code Samples - Direction Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-complex) pretty straight forward.

Comment: actually, seems like this requires the user to deal with the actual map... I'm hoping to find some function in there that will "Return Distance"

Comment: BUT it did put me onto their distance matrix, which does look like it will work.  So again, thanks.  got me to the right place in the end!

Comment: If you aren't going to display the map then you need the [The Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to display the map then use the [Google Maps API - Code Samples - Direction Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-complex).

If you just need data, then use [The Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/).

> The Google Directions API is a service that calculates directions between locations using an HTTP request. You can search for directions for several modes of transportation, include transit, driving, walking or cycling. Directions may specify origins, destinations and waypoints either as text strings (e.g. "Chicago, IL" or "Darwin, NT, Australia") or as latitude/longitude coordinates. The Directions API can return multi-part directions using a series of waypoints.